# labels in ggplot dodged barchart from table in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have following table with code:

```
tt = structure(c(7L, 13L, 24L, 30L, 30L, 38L, 35L, 45L, 37L, 
43L, 38L, 59L, 33L, 45L, 37L, 58L), .Dim = c(2L, 8L), .Dimnames = structure(list(param = c("A", 
"B"), xvar = c("5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12")), .Names = c("param", "xvar")), class = "table")
tt
     xvar
param  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
    A  7 24 30 35 37 38 33 37
    B 13 30 38 45 43 59 45 58

dd = data.frame(tt)
ggplot(dd, aes(xvar, Freq, fill=param))+ 
   geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')+
   geom_text(aes(label=Freq), position='dodge' , vjust=2)
```

[image]

But values are not getting 'dodged' and stay in center. How can they be placed properly on their bars? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't seem to define `dd` anywhere in your question.

Comment: I think `dd` is `as.data.frama(tt)`

Comment: Yes, dd=data.frame(tt). I am adding this to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `position=position_dodge(...)` instead of `position="dodge"`.

```
dd <- as.data.frame(tt)
ggplot(dd, aes(xvar, Freq, fill=param))+ 
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')+
  geom_text(aes(label=Freq), position=position_dodge(width=.9),vjust=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Good answer above, but it will only work if you have the `fill=param` on the ggplot call.